# Maxmind GeoIP - display different iframe depending on country?

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, geolocation

I've been trying to do this for the past few hours, and I've been failing miserably. Basically, I have a jquery panel on my site containing an iframe. It needs to be an iframe, there's no other way to do it.

What I want to do is have 2 different iFrames, and one to be displayed if the user's from the US, and one to be displayed if the user's from the UK. I keep on trying, but it just doesn't want to work!

Any help would be **much** apppreciated :)

Joe

P.S. I'm open to using GeoIP databases other than Maxmind, if it would make things easier.

EDIT:
One recent attempt: (to call a form that'd contain a different iFrame depending on what country they're from)

```
var country_code = geoip_country_code();
                    // List of country codes
                    if (!(country_code in {'US':'', 'UK':'', 'CA':''})) {
                        // Default country code
                    }
                           ('form1'+country_code.toLowerCase()+'.php');
```

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: I think I'm just not great with javascript. I can't work out the code, I've tried doing a redirect to Google to everyone from my country, but even that didn't want to work. I know the code for getting their country, it's just then displaying one iFrame and not displaying another that I can't work out.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: since you mention two commercial goip i will add this free geo-ip resource http://software77.net/geo-ip/

Comment: Thanks very much :) although the Maxmind API I'm using is the free version, Geolite:
http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry

Comment: @Joe, **WHAT** JavaScript?  You haven't posted any code, how can we help you?  Besides, you don't even need to do this with JavaScript.  I'm confused on what **specifically** you are trying to accomplish.  What overall methods are you using.  What GeoIP database you use has no relevance here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still in the process of learning 'real' coding languages, I only really know html/css. I haven't posted any code because I don't really have any to be honest, I try something, and it totally doesn't work, so I delete it. I've been through loads of variations now. What I'm specifically trying to accomplish is to have let's say 2 iframes, one for US, one for UK, and make 1 hidden, and 1 visible, depending on the user's country. I'll post up an example of a recent attempt in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do some thing like this, Note this is not a very good solution as it will block the rest of the page until the script has loded

```
  var country_code = geoip_country_code();

   if(country_code="AU"){
  document.write('<iframe src="/page-'+country_code+'.htm"></iframe>')
   }else if(country_code="US"){
   document.write('<iframe src="/page-'+country_code+'.htm"></iframe>')
 }
```

let me know if this what you need